# Language-dependent logo

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

How can I use a custom logo image in Drupal 8 that is language dependent? There does not seem to be an appropriate setting in the *Content and Language Translation* configuration page.

Answer (score 6):

Langauge is a visibility condition for blocks, so you could use multiple branding blocks and hard code the paths.

Setting it automatically is a little harder, language is not available in $variables in preprocess so you'd need to add it - you could add these to all preprocess functions and templates:

```
/**
 * Preprocess variables for all templates.
 * @param $variables
 */
function HOOK_preprocess(&$variables) {
  // Inject the current language into every template to ease theme development.
  $variables['current_language'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();

  // Inject a usable directory path.
  $variables['theme_path'] = base_path() . $variables['directory'];
}
```

You can use these in the branding block or page template to set a path to a language specific logo, e.g.:

```
<img src="{{ theme_path ~ '/logo-' ~ current_language.getID() ~ '.svg' }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

So you'd have logo-en.svg for english, logo-sv.svg for Swedish etc in your theme root, `getID()` just returns the two character language code.

You could go further and just build the whole thing in preprocess, just for the template you are using (either page or the branding block).

Answer (score 4):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $variables['language'] = $language;
  switch ($variables['base_plugin_id']) {

  case 'system_branding_block':
    if ($variables['content']['site_logo']['#access'] && $variables['content']['site_logo']['#uri'] && $variables['language']=='fr') {
      $variables['site_logo'] = str_replace('.svg', '-fr.svg', $variables['content']['site_logo']['#uri']);
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Jeff Burnz idea. If you want to have a more "robust" solution, you could make your own custom block type (hardcode) and put the logic there, so it could have also a fallback, if a new language logo is not available for some reason.

My second reason is: I don't like to put ANY kind of logic into presentation layer.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up implementing. Simple and flexible enough. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer for the above would be to actually use the language code already provided ( Drupal > 8.2 ) in Twig:

Drupal 8.2-8.7.5:

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/logos/logo-{{ language.getId() }}.png" alt={{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

Drupal >8.7.5:

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/logos/logo-{{ language }}.png" alt={{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

Some info on the above:

- `base_path` is the subdirectory Drupal is installed under (if your home page is at `/` you can omit that )
- `~` is the Twig concatenate operator
- `directory` is the path to your current theme

As an example, if we assume that:

- Drupal is accessible from `example.com` (not `example.com/my-drupal` or other directory )
- Current theme is located in `/themes/custom/mytheme`
- Current language code is `en`

The above example will resolve to `/themes/custom/mytheme/logos/logo-en.png`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer Nick Andriopoulos because I tried the line you wrote and flushed the cache but nothing worked. I have a Drupal 9.3.12 version so I don't know if it affects my Twig version or not.

Comment: @Zain_98 added some more info, Twig variables and explanation. If you still have issues, please use inspect element and see what the path that is generated looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works well for me :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block__system_branding_block(&$variables) {
  /**
   * this will return "en", "fr" ...
  */
  $variables['language'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  // Inject a usable directory path.
  $variables['theme_path'] = base_path() . $variables['directory'];
}
```

In templates/block--system-branding-block.html.twig :

```
{% if site_logo or site_name %}
  <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home" class="navbar-brand">
    {% if site_logo %}
      <img src="{{ theme_path }}/logo-{{ language }}.svg" alt={{ 'Home'|t }}" class="img-fluid d-inline-block align-top" />
    {% endif %}
    <span class="ml-2 d-none d-md-inline">{{ site_name }}</span>
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier hack for the lazier of us that doesn't involve any programming at all - just add the following to your `block--system-branding-block.html.twig`:

```
<img src= "{{ path('<front>') ~ 'logo.png' }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

This would look for logo.png for your site default language (usually English), rulogo.png for Russian etc.